# Set Firebug's file, Source link, column width

Tags: firebug, preferences

The Firebug console window shows the source file name and line number on the right of each entry, but it's too narrow to display file names longer than about 10 chars.

Is it possible to adjust the width of the column?

[image]

Comment: Show a picture of what you mean.  You can drag the dividing bar, and the neighboring panel usually has a red "hide" button at the lower-right.

Comment: Will do, when I get the 10 reputation points required to post images :\

Comment: Btw, it doesn't appear to be a separate panel - there's no dividing bar between the file name and the rest of the console log entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, you want to set the *SourceLink* width.

You can do this by opening ***about:config*** and then filtering for `extensions.firebug.sourceLinkLabelWidth`.

Double click and change the value to whatever works best for you.

Note that mousing over the SourceLink will also always show the full name and path.

Comment: You star!  It was the mousing over every time bit that was bugging me :)